# SSL certification not working when I don't use https before my domain name

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, ssl-certificate

So I was able to get SSL certificate for my website and it is on AWS but for some reason when I input [www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com) or mydomain.com it still shows unsecured on the browser but when I add https to mydomain.com it shows the secure icon. Please anyone with how to solve this?

Comment: Where do you serve this website from? Do you have any CDN or load balancer in front? You need to add a redirection from HTTP to HTTPS. In CloudFront this is a simple setting for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is the server has no redirection policy, you need to add redirection policy to redirect site from `HTTP` to `HTTPs`.

[image]

If you are using Application load balancer you can go through below article to set up HTTP to HTTPS redirection.

[redirect-http-to-https-using-alb](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elb-redirect-http-to-https-using-alb/)

If you are using Nginx, then you can look into [redirect-http-to-https-in-nginx](https://linuxize.com/post/redirect-http-to-https-in-nginx/#:%7E:text=The%20preferred%20method%20to%20redirect,unpredictable%20behavior%20of%20the%20server.)

[image]

[https-everywhere](https://shrikantadhikarla.wordpress.com/2013/02/17/https-everywhere-using-http-strict-transport-security/)

Answer (score 1):

SSL in web applications is only carried out when your user loads the website using HTTPS. Generally in this situation you would want to perform a redirect (a `302` is more preferable initially than a `301` as it is not permanent in the event of a rollback).

There are a number of ways you can trigger a redirection without having to make any server changes, it all depends on your infrastructure setup.

If the first point of call is CloudFront you can [update your viewer protocol policy to `Redirect HTTP to HTTPS`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-https-viewers-to-cloudfront.html). CloudFront will redirect any HTTP request before they touch the origin.

If you're using an application load balancer then you can [update your listener rule for HTTP to redirect HTTP to HTTPS](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elb-redirect-http-to-https-using-alb/). As with the above requests would not be forwarded to your host.

Otherwise if you're a Classic Load Balancer, Network Load Balancer or just plain EC2 then it falls to you modifying the configuration of your hosts to do the redirect (remembering to set to a `302`).

Below are links for most common web servers:

- [Apache](https://www.ionos.com/community/server-cloud-infrastructure/apache/guide-to-apache-redirects/)
- [Nginx](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-temporary-and-permanent-redirects-with-nginx)
- [IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/httpredirect/)
- [Tomcat](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/rewrite.html)

Once you're happy with the redirect, feel free to set as a `301`.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer work but in addition, if you are using a load balancer in your AWS EC2 instance you can follow this video link to the best explanation and practice.
[How to redirect HTTP traffic to HTTPS in the EC2 Elastic Load Balancer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GWkatWuaxls)